# I get error when i try to run this sql command (my first project)

Tags: mysql

Please can any one tell me what is wrong in this sql command?

http://2.1m.yt/Izs3wyg.jpg

this is the error which i get when i try to run it on (PHPMyadmin)..

http://2.1m.yt/ukDII_M.jpg

Comment: Please include the SQL and the error message, not images to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to define varchar() size.`varchar` datatype must have **size**.

change this line

```
category varchar not null
```

to

```
 category varchar(50) not null
```

and

```
   name varchar not null
```

to

```
 name varchar(20) not null
```

for more reference [read here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html)